# Syntax of Local.Properties In Hybris

Tags: properties-file, sap-commerce-cloud

I know that `local.Properties` overrides `project.Properties`.

I also know that that these files define… database connections, ports, build environment, frontend `HTTPS`, etc.

I further know that `project.Properties` contains *more* properties.

Will appreciate if `Hybris` experts tell me *syntax* of `local.Properties`, illustrating with some example.

Please provide correct info.

Comment: there is no syntax beyond String=String

Answer (score 5):

If we talk about the syntaxes of entries in the project.properties file, then it is `key=value`

The property files in the hybris are of two types:

1. The extension level - The property file project.properties is the configuration file that carries properties in the key-value pair for the configurations involved on the extension level For instance, Consider a property in the project.properties of the yacceleratorstorefront (storefront template) extension  `storefront.storelocator.pageSize.Desktop=10` which clearly indicates  the 'StoreLocator' results page size configuration per store. Since the store locator functionality is specific to the storefront and has no relevance for the other modules (like core, facades etc), the property is kept at the extension level.

> Please note, project.properties reside in the extension folder

2. The global level - This is the property file which is the global configuration file, and deals with the properties are extension agnostic and carry a global impact. For instance the property `commerceservices.default.desktop.ui.experience=responsive` sets the ui experience to responsive mode that specifies the deployment to be for the responsive format. 
   The local.property file supersedes all of the properties with the same key that is defined in any of the project.proprties.

> Please note, the local.properties file reside in the hybris/config folder

The hybris registry creates a property configuration map which constitutes all of the properties mentioned in the deployment configuration. The same could be managed in the HAC under platform/configuration.

The clear intent of the local.proprties file is to have information which either requires to be overriden on a global level. The override may be of different types, e.g. cart expiry time could be made different on different environments by the use of the local.property files.

For further reading, please refer to the link: https://wiki.hybris.com/display/release5/Configuring+the+Behavior+of+the+hybris+Commerce+Suite

Answer (score 4):

property call hierarchy (from primary to secondary):

- java -Dproperty.key=something
- hybris/config/local.properties
- hybris/*/(extension-name)/project.properties
- hybris/bin/platform/project.properties

and within java code:

```
   configService.getString("property.key", "last fallback value, if no propertyfile provide this key");
```

You could review all current variables using the hac interface for properties: http://localhost:9001/platform/config

Comment: AFRAID  I THIS  LINK  IS  NOT  WORKING

Comment: It should work if you have a "normally" configured hybris up and running. The platform needs to be completely started. If not -> a error occurred while init or there is a different hybris configuration (should never appear if you use the default settings)